# Grub4dos shows up while trying to boot Ubuntu 22.04 in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, 22.04

I dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I used EasyBCD to make an OS Selection with grub2. I select Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, but it shows up a grub4dos and says something like `Bash Minimal-line`. I allocated 100 GB for Ubuntu and 20 GB for swap, and I have Legacy BIOS. Also an error occurred while I finished installing Ubuntu and said something like `can't install grub on /dev/sda5. this is a fatal error` .The hibernation was on while installing Ubuntu, but I turned off hibernation now. I tried [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pkwnRROncU&t=1254s&ab_channel=munchy) while installing Ubuntu.

Edit:I fixed this problem by using the boot repair.

Comment: Why downvote with no explanation at all? Please, if you are going to downvote, you can at least spend those few seconds to also , write a short comment, explaining why it's bad. Downvoting is a good feature, but without explanations, it's pointless.
(wrote the above to the downvote(r)(s))  **Welcome to Askubuntu Cezld!** :)